# how to snap 2 specific points

Tags: modeling, snapping

I'm trying to make a low poly lantern of some sort and I want to get a frame. To do this i'm trying to get cylinders to line up with the edges of the bottom of the lantern however when i try to snap the cylinder it is facing the wrong direction how can I A) get the cylinder to face into the lantern instead of hanging off the edge and B) how can i make sure that it is centered so that it isn't skewed off to one side or another (basically how can I make it so that all the vertices are lined up straight)

[image]

Comment: Hmm... Could you zoom out and get some more pictures? I think I have a few ideas... It looks like your 3D cursor is not centered, maybe snap it to the world origin first? Perhaps I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want to use the 'Snap with Active' part of the snap feature. The active element is highlighted white by default instead of orange, and it is the individual vertex/edge/face you most recently interacted with. If you need to set your active vertex to something new, deselect and reselect that vertex.

[image]

Then it's just a simple matter of selecting the correct active vertex and snapping your mesh into place.
[image]